# How to express a property of type IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> in json schema

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I am using [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/) to interpret a bunch of C# classes into json schema. It was all going well, when I came across a type with the property:

```
public IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> MakeAndModel { get; set; }
```

When the schema renders out, the type in question looks like this:

```
"MakeAndModel": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Instinctively this feels incorrect, and I fail to see how a JSON instance generated off this schema will cleanly deserialize into the original *MakeAndModel* type.

The C# code has no attribute decoration to help the serializer - is there something we can do in this regard?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you serialize and then deserialize an instance of this?

Comment: What makes you think the schema does not describe `IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>`? From what i can tell, it does...

Comment: @elgonzo I don't see how an object with "additionalProperties" equates to a dictionary.  Do you?

Comment: Look up the documentation for the _additionalProperties_ keyword to understand what it signifies (http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.5.6). Since the children of your dictionary/json object are `IEnumerable<string>` instances, the schema specified by _additionalProperties_ matches `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @elgonzo I read that - it makes no difference.  Maybe that matches the list, but the schema itself does not match a dictionary.  It's not the same at all.

Comment: A dictionary is equivalent to a json object. How is a json object _not_ matching a dictionary and vice versa?

Comment: So how does that deserialize to a dictionary in C#?  It's not Javascript.

Comment: @elgonzo - as per Archer's comment, I cannot see how an object with additionalProperties means the same thing as a dictionary. I am probably missing something though. Please feel free to elaborate :)

Comment: @tomredfern, lets cut it short. Json does not have a dictionary data type. What now? How would you ever be able to serialize/deserialize a dictionary if json does not have anything that is equivalent to a dictionary type and that could be described by a Json schema? I guess it is just impossible to (de)serialize dictionaries then, or?

Comment: Also note that the purpose of Json schema is to describe and validate json data structures, it does not inform about particular C# data types to be used for desererialization. (Json schema is not about C# at all, so why should it be concerned with C#-specific deserialization details?) The deserializer cannot infer the C# target type(s) for deserialization from the schema, because the schema simply does not provide such information, naturally.

Comment: @elgonzo Fair point.  When you deserialize Json you have to specify the type anyway, so any Json that fits the schema should deserialize fine.  Makes sense - thanks for that.

Comment: (Just a - probably redundant - side note because we were talking about "dictionaries" in a general manner. Since Json object keys/properties are strings, the type of dictionaries you could (de)serialize straight to/from json objects would of course be required to possess string keys, just as what you have in your question.)

Comment: Fancy forming this discussion into an answer so the question can have an accepted answer? =]

Comment: @Relequestual please feel free. I will award and upvote :)